# unable to create a vertical ad banner in wordpress

Tags: html, css, wordpress

ok, I'm trying to put a html/css made vertical banner ad inside a textarea from the widget section in wordpress. So I dragged a textarea into side column, and inserted some html and add the corresponding css to the stylesheet. However, the style is not taking effect, and if I apply the style to "textarea" class, then all textarea in side pane will look the same... is there any way to apply css only to this specific textarea without affecting all others... here's the code
html

```
<div class="banner-ad-container">
            <div id="ad-header">
                <h2>Advertise Here!</h2>
            </div>
            <div id="ad-1">
                <h2>Place Your Ad Here</h2>
                <p>buy a place in our site. We have over 2000 visits everyweek</p>      
            </div>
            <div id="ad-2">
                <h2>240x400 Ad</h2>
                <p>Buy this 240x400 px ad banner and place your ad here.</p>
            </div>

            <div id="link-1">
                <a href="http://pctechtips.org/contact/"><h4>Click here for details</h4></a>                
            </div>
        </div>
```

css

```
.banner-ad-container {
    background-color: #152942;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    width: 240px;
    height: 400px;

}

#ad-header {
    border-bottom: solid 1px white;

}
```

Comment: you could have add a different class to the text area where you need a style and write css for that specific class.

Comment: how do I add a different class to that textarea? textarea are added by wordpress in the web interface admin area. I know how to add code to the text area, but not to modify the textarea itself once it is added

Comment: does the widget container have an id attribute?

Comment: @miatech It's probable that your styles are simply being overridden by other styles in the stylesheet. It may be the case that you just have to be more specific with your selector. For example;  #containing-div .banner-ad-container.

Answer (score 0):

Here is something you can use if you wanna do something specific to a certain Widget without having to rely on their ID.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/widget-css-classes/

You apply a class to the widget which will show in the main Widget wrapper which you can use to override the main Widget Element and select the child elements.

Also @mrbubbles made a good comment look if you are clearly being specific with your selector.

Tips : Use Elements inspectors of Chrome/Firefox intensively.